# Execute a windows shortcut from php

Tags: php, windows

I have a situation where I need to call a batch file from a php script... however this batch file needs to run as admin in order to work. 
My solution was to create a shortcut to the batch file and check the box to run as admin from the shortcut... however I can't get php to call the shortcut.

I have tried:

```
exec("C:/path/movefiles_admin.lnk")
```

and

```
system("cmd /c C:/path/movefiles_admin.lnk");
```

Neither of which work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
exec("START C:/path/movefiles_admin.lnk");
```

[START](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start#BKMK_examples) Starts a separate Command Prompt window to run a specified program or command.

You can run nonexecutable files through their file association by typing the name of the file as a command

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for the response... However when I try that line, I get a 500 error when the program executes... "server can't handle this request"... maybe it's hanging? I also tried "echo exec("START C:\..."), with same results.

Comment: @MattNowicky have you spaces in path? try this exec('START "C:/path with space/movefiles_admin.lnk"');

Comment: @AndreaManzi no, no spaces in the path. Here's the line:
exec("START C:/inetpub/wwwroot/internal/autofaxer/movefiles_admin.lnk")

Comment: Unfortunately the extra quotes still results in the same HTTP 500 error

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm just going about this the wrong way entirely.... with the batch file since it only works when run as admin, and maybe this could more easily be accomplished with javascript or something. All  I need to do is copy files over to a new server, and run a .ps1 on that server after copying... preferably using something where I can specify credentials to run as an admin.

Comment: Sorry, I think this is another question

Comment: I don't think it's possible, and it's not very safe, to run a php command as administrator

Comment: Doesn't matter, it's all internal anyways. I'm not trying to run the php as admin, I'm trying to call a batch file and have the batch file run as admin. But if it's not possible it's not possible... but nothing is impossible.... thanks for your replies though

Comment: Ah, very good... thank you. While this still doesn't accomplish the goal, it runs without crashing. I think the piping to enter the password isn't working correctly, as the output says "enter the password for [user]"

Comment: You know, I'm beginning to think the problem is because the folders I'm trying to copy from are in the www root of our iis webserver... even my domain admin account can't copy the files, but right click > run as admin can...

Comment: You've given me a lot of help and your answers have been correct in more than one way... so you'll get the credit for the answer lol

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP has issues executing shortcut to batch file, try executing simple read and write actions to a test.txt file. (To check whether you have PHP running in safe mode).

If it doesnt do these basic actions then you have some configuration issues.

If a program is started with exec function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.
Please refer this link for your version of PHP: [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)